# Can't import ControlP5 with Processing.js

Tags: import, processing.js, control-p5

```
import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 gui;

void setup()
{
  gui = new ControlP5(this);
}
```

The previous code, when run in Processing.js gave the error: "Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch: ReferenceError: ControlP5 is not defined" even though ControlP5 is installed on my computer. It downloaded correctly, because I have deleted the old library and downloaded it again. Can anyone please help me to make this problem go away so that I can use ControlP5 in Processing.js? People have made ControlP5 examples on OpenProcessing, and the example works when I try it online or as a local copy, but when I try to publish the code to OpenProcessing myself, it gives the error mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

ControlP5 is a Java library. It will not work with ProcessingJS. OpenProcessing runs Java Applets which is what you can create to launch your application on the web if ControlP5 is essential to your project.

To be able to run external libraries with ProcessingJS you have to, among other things, make sure you're using a JavaScript library since Java and JavaScript are two very different languages. None of these libraries will work unless they have been fully implemented internally in Processing itself.

Here's a GUI library that is designed to be cross mode, which means it should work with both Processing and ProcessingJS: https://github.com/fjenett/Guido

Also see http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html which explains what else you need to be mindful of when migrating from Processing to ProcessingJS.